# Maven can't see installed local dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with following POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I then compile and install with `mvn clean install`. I can see artefact installed in my `.m2` dir:

```
lukasz@lukasz-XPS-L701X:~$ ls  .m2/repository/com/example/demo/
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  maven-metadata-local.xml
```

I can use this file in other project when calling `javac` directly:

```
javac -cp .m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

However, when I have another Maven project that has `demo` as dependency, Maven says it can't find it.

`demo2` POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean compile` in `demo2`, I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ demo2 ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo2 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Aclass
  location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Aclass
  location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.053 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-19T10:45:57+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/254M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo2: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Aclass
[ERROR] location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] /home/lukasz/parent/demo2/src/main/java/com/example/Demo2Application.java:[11,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Aclass
[ERROR] location: class com.example.Demo2Application
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**EDIT:**
This is output of `ls -lR .m2/repository/com/example/demo/`

```
.m2/repository/com/example/demo/:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 5 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:12 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  275 Feb 19 07:07 maven-metadata-local.xml

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
total 6468
drwxr-xr-x 4 lukasz lukasz    4096 Feb 19 07:07 BOOT-INF
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 6595868 Feb 19 07:07 demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz    1410 Feb 19 01:01 demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz     701 Feb 19 07:07 maven-metadata-local.xml
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz    4096 Feb 19 07:07 META-INF
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz    4096 Feb 19 07:07 org
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz     185 Feb 19 07:07 _remote.repositories

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BOOT-INF:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 classes
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 lib

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BOOT-INF/classes:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz    0 Feb 19 07:07 application.properties
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 com

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BOOT-INF/classes/com:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 example

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BOOT-INF/classes/com/example:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 267 Feb 19 07:07 Aclass.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 694 Feb 19 07:07 DemoApplication.class

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BOOT-INF/lib:
total 6384
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz   16521 Dec 13 18:09 jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz    4596 Dec 13 18:09 jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz   23647 Dec 13 18:09 log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  305150 Jan 20 19:58 logback-classic-1.1.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  472639 Jan 20 19:57 logback-core-1.1.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz   41077 Dec 13 18:07 slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  273599 Feb 19  2016 snakeyaml-1.17.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  379905 Jan 25 13:13 spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  762701 Jan 25 13:13 spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  662119 Jan 30 19:31 spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1038200 Jan 30 19:39 spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz    2290 Jan 30 19:45 spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz    2309 Jan 30 19:45 spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1136805 Jan 25 13:14 spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1117842 Jan 25 13:13 spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  263304 Jan 25 13:14 spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/META-INF:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  558 Feb 19 07:07 MANIFEST.MF
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 maven

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/maven:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 com.example

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/maven/com.example:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 demo

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/maven/com.example/demo:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  116 Feb 19 07:07 pom.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1410 Feb 19 01:01 pom.xml

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 springframework

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 boot

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/boot:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 lukasz lukasz 4096 Feb 19 07:07 loader

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/boot/loader:
total 92
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukasz lukasz  4096 Feb 19 07:07 archive
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukasz lukasz  4096 Feb 19 07:07 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1165 Jan 30 19:26 ExecutableArchiveLauncher$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  3128 Jan 30 19:26 ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukasz lukasz  4096 Feb 19 07:07 jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1533 Jan 30 19:26 JarLauncher.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  2415 Jan 30 19:26 LaunchedURLClassLoader$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  4698 Jan 30 19:26 LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  4599 Jan 30 19:26 Launcher.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1468 Jan 30 19:26 MainMethodRunner.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1382 Jan 30 19:26 PropertiesLauncher$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1454 Jan 30 19:26 PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 16109 Jan 30 19:26 PropertiesLauncher.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1704 Jan 30 19:26 PropertiesLauncher$FilteredArchive$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  2382 Jan 30 19:26 PropertiesLauncher$FilteredArchive.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1807 Jan 30 19:26 PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukasz lukasz  4096 Feb 19 07:07 util
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1669 Jan 30 19:26 WarLauncher.class

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/boot/loader/archive:
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  906 Jan 30 19:26 Archive.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  302 Jan 30 19:26 Archive$Entry.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  399 Jan 30 19:26 Archive$EntryFilter.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  273 Jan 30 19:26 ExplodedArchive$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 4974 Jan 30 19:26 ExplodedArchive.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1068 Jan 30 19:26 ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 3792 Jan 30 19:26 ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1438 Jan 30 19:26 ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator$EntryComparator.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 7016 Jan 30 19:26 JarFileArchive.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1749 Jan 30 19:26 JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1051 Jan 30 19:26 JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/boot/loader/data:
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1531 Jan 30 19:26 ByteArrayRandomAccessData.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  551 Jan 30 19:26 RandomAccessData.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 3390 Jan 30 19:26 RandomAccessDataFile.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 3534 Jan 30 19:26 RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 2051 Jan 30 19:26 RandomAccessDataFile$FilePool.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 1341 Jan 30 19:26 RandomAccessData$ResourceAccess.class

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar:
total 136
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  4457 Jan 30 19:26 AsciiBytes.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  2169 Jan 30 19:26 Bytes.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  2943 Jan 30 19:26 CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  5449 Jan 30 19:26 CentralDirectoryFileHeader.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  4602 Jan 30 19:26 CentralDirectoryParser.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz   430 Jan 30 19:26 CentralDirectoryVisitor.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz   306 Jan 30 19:26 FileHeader.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  9657 Jan 30 19:26 Handler.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  3350 Jan 30 19:26 JarEntry.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz   262 Jan 30 19:26 JarEntryFilter.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  2002 Jan 30 19:26 JarFile$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1199 Jan 30 19:26 JarFile$2.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1427 Jan 30 19:26 JarFile$3.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 12697 Jan 30 19:26 JarFile.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1540 Jan 30 19:26 JarFileEntries$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 10924 Jan 30 19:26 JarFileEntries.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1967 Jan 30 19:26 JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1300 Jan 30 19:26 JarFile$JarFileType.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz   672 Jan 30 19:26 JarURLConnection$1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  9111 Jan 30 19:26 JarURLConnection.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  3641 Jan 30 19:26 JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  1629 Jan 30 19:26 ZipInflaterInputStream.class

.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/boot/loader/util:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukasz lukasz 4887 Jan 30 19:26 SystemPropertyUtils.class
```

Please note that I did say I can use this jar (and Aclass) when calling `javac` directly with `-cp`.

**EDIT:**

Source for Demo2Application.java:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
        Aclass c = new Aclass();
    }
}
```

Output of `jat tvf` on jar:

```
lukasz@lukasz-XPS-L701X:~/.m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT$ jar tvf demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 META-INF/
   558 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:34 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/com/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:34 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/
   267 Sun Feb 19 07:07:34 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/Aclass.class
   694 Sun Feb 19 07:07:34 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/DemoApplication.class
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:30 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 META-INF/maven/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 META-INF/maven/com.example/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 META-INF/maven/com.example/demo/
  1410 Sun Feb 19 01:01:32 CET 2017 META-INF/maven/com.example/demo/pom.xml
   116 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 META-INF/maven/com.example/demo/pom.properties
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/
 41077 Tue Dec 13 18:07:58 CET 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
  2309 Mon Jan 30 19:45:02 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
  2290 Mon Jan 30 19:45:02 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
662119 Mon Jan 30 19:31:36 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
472639 Fri Jan 20 19:57:20 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.9.jar
  4596 Tue Dec 13 18:09:14 CET 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
762701 Wed Jan 25 13:13:50 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
379905 Wed Jan 25 13:13:54 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
 16521 Tue Dec 13 18:09:00 CET 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
263304 Wed Jan 25 13:14:04 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
 23647 Tue Dec 13 18:09:06 CET 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
1136805 Wed Jan 25 13:14:18 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
1117842 Wed Jan 25 13:13:44 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
1038200 Mon Jan 30 19:39:22 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
305150 Fri Jan 20 19:58:16 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar
273599 Fri Feb 19 13:13:32 CET 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/springframework/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/
  2415 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$1.class
  1454 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
  1807 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
  4599 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.class
  1165 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher$1.class
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/
  2002 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$1.class
  9657 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Handler.class
  3350 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntry.class
  1427 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$3.class
  2943 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
   430 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryVisitor.class
  1300 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$JarFileType.class
 10924 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries.class
 12697 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile.class
  1540 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$1.class
   672 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$1.class
  1199 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$2.class
   262 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryFilter.class
  4457 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AsciiBytes.class
  4602 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryParser.class
  2169 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Bytes.class
  1629 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/ZipInflaterInputStream.class
  1967 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.class
   306 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/FileHeader.class
  3641 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
  9111 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection.class
  5449 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryFileHeader.class
  1704 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$FilteredArchive$1.class
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/
  1531 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/ByteArrayRandomAccessData.class
  3534 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
  2051 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$FilePool.class
  1341 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessData$ResourceAccess.class
  3390 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile.class
   551 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessData.class
  4698 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
  1533 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
  1468 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/MainMethodRunner.class
  2382 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$FilteredArchive.class
  1382 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$1.class
  3128 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
  1669 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/WarLauncher.class
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/
  1749 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.class
  3792 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator.class
  1068 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
  1051 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class
   302 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$Entry.class
  7016 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive.class
  4974 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive.class
   906 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive.class
  1438 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator$EntryComparator.class
   399 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$EntryFilter.class
   273 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$1.class
 16109 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.class
     0 Sun Feb 19 07:07:38 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/
  4887 Mon Jan 30 19:26:16 CET 2017 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/SystemPropertyUtils.class
```

Comment: what is the full list of files in .m2/repository/com/example/demo/?

Comment: It doesn't really tell that it can't find the dependency. It tells that it can't find the class AClass. Does this class exist in the jar file? What's the output of `jar tvf .m2/repository/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`? What's the source code of Demo2Application.java?

Comment: OK. So that confirms it: your class is not in the jar. Or rather, it's under the BOOT-INF/classes/com/example directory instead of being under the com/example directory. This jar file is not a jar file that can be used as a library. It's an uber jar jar file that has been created by the Spring-Boot plugin to contain all the dependencies and classes of your first app, along with a spring boot loader that uses a custom classloader in order to load the application classes and the dependencies from the uber jar.

Comment: If the jar shouldn't be a Spring boot app, but a simple library, then just don't use the Spring boot plugin in that project. If it's supposed to be a library *and* a spring boot app at the same time (which is strange), then split it into two projects: one that produces a library, and a second one which is a spring boot app, contains just the main class of the app (and the other classes that shouldn't be in the library), and has the library as dependency.

Comment: You're right. I got confused by the fact that it worked when called from javac. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is not in the jar. Or rather, it's under the `BOOT-INF/classes/com/example` directory instead of being under the `com/example` directory.

This jar file is not a jar file that can be used as a library. It's an uber jar file that has been created by the Spring-Boot plugin to contain all the dependencies and classes of your first app, along with a spring boot loader that uses a custom classloader to load the application classes and the dependencies from the uber jar.

If the jar shouldn't be a Spring boot app, but a simple library, then just don't use the Spring-Boot plugin in that project.

If it's supposed to be a library and a Spring Boot app at the same time (which is strange), then split it into two projects: one that produces a library, and a second one which is a Spring Boot app, contains just the main class of the app (and the other classes that shouldn't be in the library), and has the library as dependency.